# Control Chrome Web Inspector in Javascript console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

Is there anyway to control the Chrome Web Inspector in the JavaScript console?

For example, say I wanted to select an element (#test_element) in the "Elements" panel. Normally I right click on the element and choose "Inspect Element".

I'd like to do this in the JavaScript console, using something like:

```
webInspector.inspectElement("#test_element");
```

I'd like to be able to access the entire UI of the web inspector this way. I'm open to using extensions for this as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`inspect`](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api#inspectobject) for this purpose. Since you want to use a selector, combine it with the console's [`$`](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api#selector) <sup>alias for `document.querySelector`</sup>. If the page overrides `$`, because it uses jQuery, use `$$(selector)[0]` to get a reference to the DOM element (anything would do, as long as it's a reference to a DOM node).

[image]

Comment: You can also just run the selector and return the Element to the console. The WebKit inspektor does display them like this

Answer (score 1):

From the [Command Line Api Reference](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api)

> **`inspect(object)`**
>
> Opens and selects the specified element or object in the appropriate
>   panel: either the Elements panel for DOM elements and the Profiles
>   panel for JavaScript heap objects.
>
> The following example opens the first child element of document.body
>   in the Elements panel:
>
> ```
> inspect(document.body.firstChild);
> ```